# Delay a signal in VHDL Testbench

Tags: vhdl, test-bench

I would like to put a delay on a signal in my testbench. The problem is that I need hundreds of clock cycles and thus I don't want to use hundreds of intermediate signals.

Since this is just for a simulation use, is there any way to add a delay with unsynthetisable code (perhaps with WAIT or AFTER)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use a `transport` delay. By default, if you make a delayed assignment, this will use an 'inertial' delay model:

```
my_sig_delayed <= my_sig after 100 ns;
```

However, with this example, if your signal toggles more than once in 100 ns, your `my_sig_delayed` signal will not follow it as you might expect it to. By using a `transport` delay, you replicate a 'delay line'.

```
my_sig_delayed <= transport my_sig after 100 ns;
```

For a more detailed explanation, try this http://www.gmvhdl.com/delay.htm

---

An alternative would be to use a shift register with a length of whatever delay you need:

```
signal delay_line : std_logic_vector(255 downto 0) := (others => '0');
```

...

```
process (clk)
begin
  if (rising_edge(clk)) then
    delay_line <= delay_line(delay_line'left-1 downto 0) & my_sig;
  end if;
end process;

my_sig_delayed <= delay_line(delay_line'left);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations. Indeed I tried the first way which was the more obvious to me, but since my signal period is less than the delay it couldn't work. If there isn't any other way I'll use the second option.

Comment: @A.Kieffer it should work if you use the `transport` keyword per the second line of code above.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get the point at first look. I tried `transport` and it works well. Thank you @scarry_jeff!